# How to leave trails

Tags: scripting

Is there a way to make Blender leave trails or, in other words, not clear the canvas (I know "canvas" isn't Blender jargon). In Three.js, there is an option to "Preserve drawing buffer" which basically makes the library never erase the canvas. Ex: `renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ preserveDrawingBuffer: true })`. Is there anything similar to this for Blender?

Here is an example using Three.js of what can be achieved from this:
[image]
(Source:http://brangerbriz.net/labs/threejs_playGnd/)

Comment: There are [dupli-frames](http://blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/duplication/dupliframes.html), but they operate in 3D space (leaving behind actual instances of the mesh). Are you looking to achieve this effect in an animation? The viewport? The BGE?

Comment: An array with an object offset? - Animation nodes [can do trails easily](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HjtqG3WzvQI&list=PLFSQhJg6cGLKq8WbouMNBOHbMd7xUhuom&index=8)

Comment: Animation nodes looks cool, but it's a little heavier than what I want. I just want to say "Go" and whatever was in the last frame to still be there. Dupli-frames is cool too, but I don't want to need a path. I am trying to achieve the effect in an animation.

Comment: There is a VSE addon for compositing echo frames, or stacking previous rendered frames on top of each other.

Answer (score 1):

Try rendering to a bunch of PNGs with alpha, and then combining them afterward in an image editor (like [GIMP](https://gimp.org)).